# Maximum temperature of an elliptical thermodynamic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat-engine

Given a heat engine made from the curve
$$V(t)=V_0 +A \cos(\omega t); \qquad P(t)=P_0-B \sin(\omega t).$$
What are the hottest and coldest points of this cycle, and what are the temperatures at those points?

I've tried setting $dT/dt=0$ with $T=PV/(Nk)$ many different ways, including stuff like having $P$ in terms of $V$ or using Lagrange multipliers, but the equations were always too messy. Any ideas?

Comment: In[4]:= Solve[D[(V0 + A Cos[w t]) (P0 - B Sin[wt]), t] == 0, 
  t] // Simplify

Out[4]= {{t -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(2 \[Pi] C[1])/w, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, {t -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(\[Pi] + 2 \[Pi] C[1])/w, 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers]}} doesn't seem too messy! You're on the right track.